# Why is it possible to "loop" a filesystem by mounting it to one of its folders?

Tags: filesystems, mount, loop-device

**/dev/sda5** is mounted at **/** and it's my filesystem

```
piotr@thinkpad:~$ sudo mkdir /home/mpoint
piotr@thinkpad:~$ sudo mount /dev/sda5 /home/mpoint
```

so now I can do:

```
piotr@thinkpad:~$ cd /home/mpoint/home/mpoint
```

and when I'm in second mpoint directory, it's empty.

My questions are:

1. Why is it possible to "loop" a filesystem by mounting it to one of its folders?
2. Why this second mpoint dir is empty?

Comment: What happens if you run `sudo mount /dev/sda5 /home/mpoint/home/mpoint` ?

Comment: sure... so, why shouldn't you be able to mount to any directory even on the same drive? The second mpoint is empty because if it's not a mount point, it's just an empty directory. Would be interesting to see what happens if you try to create files in that empty directory

Comment: @pLumo it works and I can go to ```/home/mpoint/home/mpoint/home/mpoint```

Comment: I assume that is then empty (as it is an empty directory where nothing is mounted. @pLumo: I assume files created there would work as expected for files in a directory where you mount stuff, i.e. be hidden by the mount.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When mounting a file system one add an extra layer for the system. The mount-point is an absolute path that normally hides the contents of the target. To have a closer look using `stat` can be of help. I.e:

First prepare a test case:

```bsh
# mkdir /mnt/other
# echo hi > /mnt/other/hello.txt
# cat /mnt/other/hello.txt
hi
# stat -c %i /mnt/other
6424680
```

Then mount

```bsh
# mount / /mnt/other
# cat /mnt/other/hello.txt
cat: cannot access '/mnt/other/hello.txt': No such file or directory
# stat -c %i /mnt/other
2
# stat -c %i /
2
# stat -c %i /mnt/other/mnt/other
6424680
# cat /mnt/other/mnt/other/hello.txt
hi
```

As you can see the inode for the mount-point changes from inode 6424680 to 2 (which is the inode for root directory<sup>1</sup>). The contents of that directory is hidden as far as the mount point is concerned, but still present on the disk. It is a layer above the file-system.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>and parent to root, `.` and `..`</sub>

---

The path `/mnt/other/mnt/other` is not a mount-point and holds the original content for the inode of that directory. In your case it is empty, in my case it has one file; Though you *could* make it a mount point as well:

```bsh
# mount / /mnt/other/mnt/other
# stat -c %i /mnt/other/mnt/other
2
# stat -c %i /mnt/other/mnt/other/mnt/other
6424680
# cat /mnt/other/mnt/other/mnt/other/hello.txt
hi
```

As for *why*, then why not. Unless it damages the system let the user do what ever they want. That's *not saying* one can not do things that damages the system albeit in this case the incentive to add a blocker is not present from what I can see. For what ever reason people might even want to create another view at a mount-point even of the root tree itself.

Further *nix systems have a single directory tree as opposed to e.g. Windows with *drives* that has letters *A:*, *B:*, *C:*, *…*. As per start of man mount:

> All files accessible in a Unix system are arranged in one big tree, the file hierarchy, rooted at /. These files can be spread out over several devices. The mount command serves to attach the filesystem found on some device to the big file tree.

Comment: fantastic explanation, thanks a lot <3

Comment: No, a mount point is not an "absolute path". See `mkdir -p foo/bar quux; mount -B / foo/bar; mv foo quux/baz`: At the end of that, `qqux/baz/bar` is the same mount point `foo/bar` was and you can unmount it with `umount quux/baz/bar` (bind-mount used for convenience, it makes no difference)

Comment: Even if it damages the system. Unix/Linux is a very powerful system. Shooting oneself in the foot is allowed, but avoidable, if one doesn't commit UTBLT (Using Tool Before Learning Tool).

Comment: @Căcărău  Sure one can *mount*, move tings around or navigate using relative paths - but the mount-point when accessed is absolute. If not one could `cd /mnt/other/mnt/other/mnt/other/mnt/other` ... ad infinity after first mount.

Comment: @waltinator: Point I was trying to make is that if it does not damage the system it's even less incentive to add a blocker. It could be better formulated I guess. I'll try to re-phrase. Right now its pizza.

Comment: @ibuprofen 1. from the point of view of the OS (the entity which is managing mounts), any path is absolute. But a mount point is not a "path", as my example demonstrates. 2 "If not one could cd .. ad infinity" yet they don't, despite mounts NOT being implemented as you suggest ;-)

Comment: tl;dr; I don't believe in [lie-to-children](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie-to-children) as a way of explaining things. So please try harder than suggesting that a mount is simply a path prefix.

Comment: @Căcărău Have not said a mount is simply a path prefix. All I have pointed out is that it has an absolute path in the file hierarchy. Now, if you feel lied to because of that I'm sorry.

Comment: It's not about feelings, it's about your answer being technically incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

I'll answer your questions in reverse order.

> 2. Why this second mpoint dir is empty?

Because nothing is there - the directory is empty and noting is mounted on that location.

> 1. Why is it possible to "loop" a filesystem by mounting it to one of its folders?

Probably because it would be a lot of work to prevent it and nothing bad can really come from it. And to address your comment: No directory gets more than one parent by this, `/home/mpoint` is not the same directory as `/home/mpoint/home/mpoint`.

Comment: Exactly. Why should it not be possible?

Comment: right, my question about beeing empty was stupid one... but @pLumo I think it should not be possible because in Linux fs each directory can have only one parent directory, I studied this while I was wondering why I can't use hard links to directories

Comment: But, each directory has only one parent.